# Swipe to close sliding menu by J.Feinstein

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am using J.Feinstein library of sliding menu and it works great... The only problem i have is that it closes only if i touch outside the sliding menu or if i swipe from right to left from outside the sliding menu..

**But what actually i want is that it will also swipe from right to left to close when i swipe it by finger on it, not only from outside of it...**
I searched a lot.. In fact i read the source code of library and found the function `getSlidingMenu(true);` but that does not fulfill my requirement .. I am new to android... Kindly help me out and tell me how to do this..

Here is my piece of code..

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity{

   // Tab titles
   private String[] tabs = { "First", "Second", "Third" };

   public ViewPagerActivity() {
      super();
   }



   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setTitle(R.string.viewpager);
      setContentView(R.layout.pager);


     // customize the SlidingMenu
     final SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
     sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
     sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
     sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
     sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
     sm.setScrollBarStyle(2);
     sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
     //sm.setSlidingEnabled(true);
     //sm.setTouchmodeMarginThreshold(2);

     getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(true);
     setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this type of sliding then use view pager with sliding....

http://javapapers.com/android/android-image-slider-tutorial/

this will surely help you and you will no have to face this kind of problem...